# R Shiny - collateral issues when a selectInput depends on another

Tags: r, shiny

When a selectInput depends on another selectInput, we get a collateral issue that takes a fraction of a second, but it can be annoying.

As I said, for a fraction of a second we get inconsistent data because the main selectInput changes its value, invalidating outputs that depend on it. Those outputs start to compute, but after the second selectInput is repopulated, the output is invalidated again and it starts again.

The example below can be used to reproduce what I described.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

df <- as.data.frame(list(food=c("fruit", "fruit", "fruit", "vegetable", "vegetable"),
                         item=c("banana", "grape", "strawberry", "asparagus", "kale")))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("food", "Select the food type", choices = df$food %>% unique()),
      selectInput("item", "Select the item", choices = NULL)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("sentence")
    )
  )
)
  
  
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$food, {
    req(input$food)
    choices <- df %>% filter(food == input$food) %>% select(item)
    updateSelectInput(session, "item", choices = choices)
  })
  
  output$sentence <- renderText({
    s <- paste(input$item, "is a", input$food)
    print(s)
    s
  })
  
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For the user who is looking at the webpage, everything seems to be fine. However, if we look at the console we will see:

```
[1] " is a fruit"                <- Starting the App
[1] "banana is a fruit"          <- After the `item` is populated
[1] "banana is a vegetable"      <- Selecting "vegetable"
[1] "asparagus is a vegetable"   <- After the `item` is repopulated
```

Adding a `req(input$item)` to the `output$sentence` as below, will help a bit

```
  output$sentence <- renderText({
    req(input$item)
    s <- paste(input$item, "is a", input$food)
    print(s)
    s
  })
```

The output for this would be:

```
[1] "banana is a fruit"          <- After the `item` is populated
[1] "banana is a vegetable"      <- Selecting "vegetable"
[1] "asparagus is a vegetable"   <- After the `item` is repopulated
```

The example below using a `reactiveValues` works, but this is a tiny example just to be reproducible. I believe this would be much more complex in a big system.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  state <- reactiveValues(
    food = NULL,
    item = NULL
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$food, {
    req(input$food)
    state$food <- input$food
    state$item <- NULL
    choices <- df %>% filter(food == input$food) %>% select(item) %>% pull()
    state$item <- choices[1]
    updateSelectInput(session, "item", choices = choices)
  })
  
  output$sentence <- renderText({
    req(state$item)
    s <- paste(state$item, "is a", state$food)
    print(s)
    s
  })
  
}
```

Questions:

- How could I prevent running `output$sentence` till the second selectInput is populated with new data?
- Would the solution above be the only one?
- Would be better to use one `reactiveVal` for each variable to create the "state"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for using `isolate()` in the`renderText` to prevent that it gets triggered by a changge in `input$food`, i.e. do `s <- paste(input$item, "is a", isolate(input$food))`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

df <- as.data.frame(list(
  food = c("fruit", "fruit", "fruit", "vegetable", "vegetable"),
  item = c("banana", "grape", "strawberry", "asparagus", "kale")
))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("food", "Select the food type", choices = df$food %>% unique()),
      selectInput("item", "Select the item", choices = NULL)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("sentence")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  hist <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$food, {
    req(input$food)
    choices <- df %>%
      filter(food == input$food) %>%
      pull(item)
    
    updateSelectInput(session, "item", choices = choices)
  })

  output$sentence <- renderText({
    req(input$item)
    s <- paste(input$item, "is a", isolate(input$food))
    print(s)
    s
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: So, if I have one `output` that depends on `N nested selectInputs`, I will have to `isolate` all but the bottom one. Is that right?

Comment: In general I would say yes. Of course is it not necessary to isolate each input separately, i.e. you could isolate several lines or multiple inputs at once.